# Why isn't memory usage of a virtual machine monitor-able?

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, monitoring, memory-usage

While checking my AWS instance (CloudWatch), I noticed that there's no monitor data for memory usage. There are I/O usage like disk and network, as well as CPU usage.

From my own experiences in using VMware Workstation, I also find it hard to determine memory usage of a VM from the host environment.

Is the memory usage of a VM watch-able from host OS? If not, why?

Comment: I can’t explain why there is a difference. But I can say that RAM usage can be monitored in both AWS and in VMWare. In the former, it is done by configuring the AWS systems manager agent. And with VMWare it might require vmtools but I’m not sure on that. My best guess is that the operating system consumes everything allocated to it in a virtual machine, and it requires OS level insight in to what portion of that memory is free or used by the OS and applications.